# Access list elements that are not equal to a specific value

Tags: python

I am searching through a list like this:

`my_list = [['a','b'],['b','c'],['a','x'],['f','r']]`

and I want to see which elements come with `'a'`. So first I have to find lists in which `'a'` occurs. Then get access to the other element of the list. I do this by `abs(pair.index('a')-1)`

```
for pair in my_list:
    if 'a' in pair:
       print( pair[abs(pair.index('a')-1)] )
```

Is there any better pythonic way to do that?
Something like: `pair.index(not 'a')` maybe?

UPDATE:

- Maybe it is good to point out that `'a'` is not necessarily the first element.
- in my case, `['a','a']` doesn't happen, but generally maybe it's good to choose a solution which handles this situation too

Comment: So what is your expected output? x and b? or [a,x] and [a,b]?

Comment: How about [x for x in my_list if x[0] == 'a']

Comment: You actually don't need the `abs()`, since Python lists accept negative indices.  Index `-k` refers to the `k`th element from the tail of the list.  So `pair.index('a')-1` will work just fine.

Comment: @augurar hmmm... good point :D yep you're right

Comment: @Rudi 'a' is not always the first element. maybe my example was not comprehensive enough. augurar's and COLDSPEED's answers were what I wanted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for elements that accompany `a`? If so, a simple list comprehension will do:

```
In [110]: [x for x in my_list if 'a' in x]
Out[110]: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'x']]
```

---

If you just want the elements and not the pairs, how about getting rid of `a` before printing:

```
In [112]: [(set(x) - {'a'}).pop() for x in my_list if 'a' in x]
Out[112]: ['b', 'x']
```

I use a `set` because `a` could either be the first *or* second element in the pair.

Comment: second part of your answer is exactly what I want! Thanks

Comment: @Alireza Beware the code might break if you have a `(a, a)` pair. Will that happen?

Comment: @COLDSPEED in my case this doesn't happen, but if it is the case, I guess we need to use .index() but considering what augurar mentioned about not using abs()

Comment: You don't need the `list()` inside the comprehension. You could also [`pop` from a `set`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.pop).

Comment: @MSeifert Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

```
my_list = filter(
   lambda e: 'a' not in e,
   my_list
)
```

Note that in python 3, this returns a filter object instance. You may want to wrap the code in a list() command to get a list instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

That technique works ok here, but it may be more efficient, and slightly more readable, to do it using sets. Here's one way to do that.

```
def paired_with(seq, ch):
    chset = set(ch) 
    return [(set(pair) - chset).pop() for pair in seq if ch in pair]

my_list = [['a','b'], ['b','c'], ['x','a'], ['f','r']]

print(paired_with(my_list, 'a'))
```

**output**

```
['b', 'x']
```

---

If you want to do lots of tests on the same list, it would be more efficient to build a list of sets.

```
def paired_with(seq, ch):
    chset = set(ch) 
    return [(pair - chset).pop() for pair in seq if ch in pair]

my_list = [['a','b'], ['b','c'], ['x','a'], ['f','r']]
my_sets = [set(u) for u in my_list]
print(my_sets)
print(paired_with(my_sets, 'a'))
```

**output**

```
[{'b', 'a'}, {'c', 'b'}, {'x', 'a'}, {'r', 'f'}]
['b', 'x']
```

This will fail if there's a pair like `['a', 'a']`, but we can easily fix that:

```
def paired_with(seq, ch):
    chset = set(ch) 
    return [(pair - chset or chset).pop() for pair in seq if ch in pair]

my_list = [['a','b'], ['b','c'], ['x','a'], ['f','r'], ['a', 'a']]
my_sets = [set(u) for u in my_list]
print(paired_with(my_sets, 'a'))
```

**output**

```
['b', 'x', 'a']
```